# How do I upgrade web2py from the command-line

Tags: upgrade, web2py

For some reason I can't get access to my web2py admin page via https. So what is the equivalent command-line call for clicking the "upgrade to latest web2py version" button on the admin page?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed web2py using pip, then you can upgrade it by running

```
pip install --upgrade web2py
```

you might need to add `sudo` at the beginning of the command depending on your system configuration.

Comment: Will that overwrite any bespoke apps I have in applications/ ?